# I am accessing a MySQL database using the .NET connector and getting the error "Guid should contain 32 digits and 4 dashes"

Tags: mysql, guid

I have a .NET application which allows users to access various databases by providing a connection string and a provider.

One of the databases which users want to access is a MySQL database (not mine so I can't change it) where the primary keys are all stored as GUIDs.

My application can access records in various tables in that database when using the MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver.

But using exactly the same code (taking into account that ODBC needs a ? in place of a parameter name whereas the .NET connector needs the "@name" syntax), and attempting to read the same records in the same tables but this time with the MySQL .NET Connector (V6.1.3 as well as v6.2.2), then I get the error "Guid should contain 32 digits with 4 dashes ...".

Is there something wrong with the .NET Connector, or is there something I need to specify somewhere to make it work?

Comment: how does the .NET driver know it is a GUID? GUID is not a native MySQL data type, so it cannot've deduced it from the table structure.

Comment: How is the column containing the guid specified and how does your failing query look like ?

Comment: Roland: That's a good question!  I wish I knew the answer.  As I said, this isn't my data base it's someone else's, so I'm just issuing a SELECT WHERE id = @paramName call.  I only know the id is a GUID because I was able to retrieve the data using the ODBC driver, and when I look at that I see it looks GUID-like.

Comment: @RolandBouman .Net Driver does know. In fact older version of .net connector (5 series) reads the underlying binary directly as a .NET GUID. Perhaps logic has been incorporated in the connector itself since its for .NET. The documentation of the connector itself ays it treats binary 16 and char 36 as GUID by default! Newer versions (6 series) reads binary as .NET byte array though. Though, I too find these weird

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Well, after scouting around a bit, I thought I would see if MySQL had released a later version of the .NET Connector than I had.  I found https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/.  That says something about the error that I was receiving, and speaks about an option "old guids=true" in the connection string (it doesn't say when and how you should use this, but that it didn't work properly in version 6.1.3).

I tried putting "oldguids=true" in my connection string, and then my generic application worked.

Answer (score 4):

I had the same problem, but it was caused by a Stored Procedure in which I was declaring a variable of type `Char(36)` and MySql (I'm guessing the Connector) was interpreting that as a GUID. So by changing its size to 37 (or whatever) it worked.

Comment: @nawfal Glad to have been of help. :)

Answer (score 0):

```
server=localhost;user=root;password=abc123;database=test;old guids=true;
```

Watch out `old guids=true` part.